# Error while Searching LDAP

Tags: python, unix, ldap

I am running a python script to connect and bind to LDAP but while searching LDAP it throws this error.
using this function: `search_s()`

but error:
`{'info': '00002024: LdapErr: DSID-0C060595, comment: No other operations may be performed on the connection while a bind is outstanding., data 0, v1772', 'desc': 'Server is busy'}`

Please help. What shall i do to resolve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show the code you are using ?

Comment: is the server actually busy?

Comment: Nopes server is not busy

Comment: so adding a loop to retry a few times with a a try/except makes no difference?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, you send a bind to LDAP, then you send a search. The problem is that you're sending the second request before the server's handled the first and it gets annoyed and punts you, hence the "I'm busy" response.

The solution is to tell the Python ldap client to wait for a result before proceeding, thus this:

```
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://fnord.com')
l.bind('thisismyname', 'andthisismyquest')
l.search_s(scope, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, query, attributes)
```

becomes this:

```
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://fnord.com')
l.bind('thisismyname', 'andthisismyquest')
l.result()                                 # THIS IS THE LINE THAT MAKES IT WORK
l.search_s(scope, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, query, attributes)
```

When I made this change to my script it started working reliably every time.

UPDATE:

I found the right, right way to do it:

```
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://fnord.com')
l.bind_s('thisismyname', 'andthisismyquest') # S IS FOR SYNCHRONOUS, IS GOOD ENOUGH FOR ME
l.search_s(scope, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, query, attributes)
```